# Getting the product collection from an advanced search

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalogsearch, product-collection, ee-1.13

I'm trying to get the product collection containing only the products that appear in a search, from inside app\design\frontend[theme]\catalog\layer\view.phtml

I've tried:

```
$search = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced');
$searchCollection = $search->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

and

```
$searchCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getProductCollection();
$searchCollection = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->prepareProductCollection( $searchCollection );
$searchCollection = $searchCollection->getProductCollection();
```

Both of these return every single product on the site, not just the ones in the search results.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This was the only working solution I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978893/whats-the-proper-way-to-call-catalogsearch-from-a-custom-block-in-magento

Though I did replace

```
$searchText = 'ipad';
```

with

```
$searchText = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();
```

to make it dynamic.

Comment: if u got the answer. then close the question.

Comment: This is a working solution, but it is bulky. I'm pretty sure there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

Well we know the product collection is loaded and present somewhere, so rather than querying the database again, if we know we are in the context of a search results page it is probably safe to just get the collection from the list block.

On a `/catalogsearch/result` page the list block will be at `search_result_list`, so we can fetch it from any block or template with:

`$oListBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('search_result_list')`

And from here we can get the product collection off the block with:

`$oListBlock->getLoadedProductCollection();`

Also the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::getLoadedProductCollection()` method calls `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection` which does some digging for a usable product collection, which is handy if you're writing a block that needs to be used in a few different circumstances.

Comment: worked great and seems the simplest way to accomplish this and the most D.R.Y friendly method

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this,

```
$search = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$searchCollection = $search->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', '3');
```

Comment: I don't think so, no. I am on the URL /catalogsearch/result/?q=example and trying to get the collection of products that matches the query "example" from inside app\design\frontend[theme]\catalog\layer\view.phtml so that I can make a list of categories that are used by the products returned in the search. I can't seem to get a collection that only contains the search results from this file. (Obviously app\design\frontend[theme]\catalog\product\list.phtml just uses $this->getLoadedProductCollection() but that's not available in layer.phtml)